# When I add a small tag in bootstrap navbar, why does line-height increase 1px?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I add a `<small>` tag in a Twitter Bootstrap navbar, why does line-height increase by 1px?

```
<li><a href="#"><small>welcome</small>Link</a></li>
```

`<a>` tag 21px , `<li>` tag 51px

I want to know why?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><small>welcome</small>Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Inspect the DOM and search for borders in <small> tag

Comment: Clarify your question I don't see any problem here http://www.bootply.com/RN2xzio0GH

Comment: @Danko His problem, which you can see in your bootply, is that when a `<small>` element is inside the `<a>` tag, it increases the height  of the `<a>` by 1 pixel. You can compare it to the other `<li><a></a></li>` elements.

Comment: sorry ,my code not full , now ,you try it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your css file (to override bootstrap.css):

```
.navbar-nav>li>a {
  line-height: inherit;
}
```

you will get rid of the 1px.

Comment: your methord is right ,but i want to know reason . why smaller font's line-height is higher.